# Free SQL Express - linked DBs

Tags: sql-server-express

I currently use Access Database. Nevertheless I face the issues of 2 GB limit. My workaround is to make 2 different DBs and just link them - so I can use 4GB,

And my question is: is it possible to introduce similar workaround in case of free SQL Server Express solution? What I mean: if I reach the limit 10 GB may I store some tables in second DB and just link it with the first main one DB?

Will it work? If yes - how many such a databeses may I link each other?

I would appreciate your advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible.** You can create multiple databases on the same instance and there are no limits to the number of databases. But each database should be **less than 10GB**. 
Also one server can use only **1GB RAM**. However, you can install multiple instances of SQL Server on the same machine, each of them will use 1GB RAM and you will be able to link them with no limit.

You should know that described solution has not a big performance reserve. It is applicable only for application with low load. Otherwise you can upgrade to other editions of SQL Server. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016)